# UIScrollView, magic scrollable area

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

A simple example is used for demonstration only strange features of the UIScrollView.

Have an instance of UIScrollView that occupies the entire screen area. An instance of UIView is placed on UIScrollView instance and entirely overlapping it.

ScrollView is configured so that all swipes on him transferred in the overlapping View and the scroll didn't happen. So it should work, all swipes redirected to the view, since it completely overlaps the ScrollView.
But there is a region located in the lower left corner of the screen, when you swipe where sometimes (not always) starts scrolling.
What is this magical area? How to avoid this behavior?
Repeated only on the device (tried on iPhone6, iPhone6+, iPad Air), on the simulator was not able to repeat.

That's how we create and custom views:

`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MyScrollView *sv = [[MyScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    sv.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
    sv.delaysContentTouches = NO;
    sv.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(sv.bounds.size.width, sv.bounds.size.height + 300);
    sv.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:sv];

    UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sv.bounds];
    topView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [sv addSubview:topView];
}`

MyScrollView has a single overridden method:

`- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    return YES;
}`

Thanks, sorry for my English.

Comment: when do you add swipe gesture ?

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: 1. I don't add swipe gesture. There is only the code provided above.
2. I don't want to allow scrolling.